# Commit updates to UpdatePanel before synchronous process ends

Tags: asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have a button click configured as an asynchronous postback trigger in ASP.NET AJAX. I want to hide a panel immediately, and then continue executing the rest of the code in the event handler.

How can I do this?

Comment: Effectively I'm looking for Application.DoEvents() functionality from the Windows Forms model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've implemented this by using a timer. When I click the button it performs the actions that I want done right away, and a separate timer Tick event completes processing asynchronously.